# Showing $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)||n|^ℓ < \infty$ implies that $f$ is $C^ℓ$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathbb{T} = [- \pi, \pi]$.

**Goal:** Prove the following:

> Let $f : \mathbb{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a $2\pi$-periodic and integrable, $ℓ \ge 1$. If $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)||n|^ℓ < \infty$, then $f$ is $C^ℓ$.

**Attempt:**

First we show the base case, where $n = 1$. So suppose that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(n)||n|$ converges. Then

$$
\left|\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{i n \theta} \right| \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left| \hat{f}(n) \right| \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left| \hat{f}(n) \right| |n| < \infty
$$

This then implies that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta}$ converges uniformly to some $g$ by the Weierstrauss M-test.

Moreover, since each $\hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta}$ is a continuous function, then the partial sums $\sum_{n \le |N|} \hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta}$ are also continuous. Then by the uniform limit theorem, $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta}$ uniformly converges to a continuous function.

But then how do we know that

$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta} = f?
$$

How do we know that $f$ is not just continuous, but differentiable (and that its derivative is continuous)? And then how do we cover the inductive step case?

Answer (score 0):

The map from $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$ to $\mathbb Z$ given by $g\to (\hat g (n))_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is injective. Since both $L^1$ functions in our problem, namely

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta} \text { and }\,\,f(\theta),$$

have the same Fourier coefficients, they are the same a.e. Thus $f$ is a.e. equal to the continuous function given by the series in $(1).$ Furthermore the series of derivatives in $(1)$ is

$$\tag 2\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} in\hat{f}(n) e^{in \theta},$$

which is uniformly convergent by the hypothesis and Weierstass M. By the standard result on differentiation and uniform convergence, the series in $(1)$ has derivative given by $(2),$ which is continuous. Hence $f\in C^1.$

Comment: How can we go about the inductive process for this?